# How I can build Eclipse C++ project with CMake from the Linux console ( no GUI is available )

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, cmake

I have Eclipse C++ project and want to build this on Linux server ( no GUI ) with CMake. How can I generate CMakelists.txt from this Eclipse project?

Comment: Note sure that you can. If you are remoting to the server, are you sure you don't have access to a GUI at all? If you connect with `ssh -x user@server.address`, and try to run eclipse&, you probably would get a gui. Or do you have the project locally and just wan to build on the server? If that's the case, just create the CMakeLists.txt yourself. There are guides for integrating cmake into eclipse, but none that I found for a conversion.

Comment: Without a lot more detail, this question will likely be closed for being too broad.

Comment: I think you have to write the CMakeLists.txt by your own. In my opinion this is anyway the better approach, because then you can create multiple build chains (Makefile, eclipse-projects). Without GUI you can then create makefiles with CMake

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=186847

Comment: I don't think there is a way to **generate** CMake files from existing Eclipse projects. You have to write the CMake files on your own, structuring them to match your Eclipse project's setup and build hierarchies.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you write a CMake generator from eclipse files, there is no tools that will produce a seamless transition between the two automatically, and I don't think there is a 1:1 relationship between the two.

The best would be to learn CMake and write the file that match your current project. After that, there are ways that eclipse can use this CMake file afterwards so you don't duplicate your project definition.